# How do I speed up eigenvalue computations?

Tags: performance-tuning

I want to get to eigenvalues of a 8x8 matrix, but with quite complicated trigonometric terms in it. I already FullSimplified it, expanded it, the matrix is in its easiest form and Mathematica  has been calculating for four hours already and I still have no eigenvalues. Is there any way I can make Mathematica faster? It can use all my computers computational power if it wants to, I just cannot wait hours and hours for every calculation, since I need them to go on with my research.

Comment: Do you want to obtain the eigenvalues numerically or symbolically? Have you tried `Eigenvalues[N@yourMatrix]`?

Comment: If your matrix is sparse (lots of zeros) you might try defining it a s a "SparseArray" and then feed that to Eigenvalues[].